# merging files with awk by matching - awk not printing all array assignments

Tags: arrays, awk, merge

I am trying to merge two files based on values that match in both files. Here is an example:
File 1:

```
Geneid  Chr Length  DP_D_9_8_21_B_contigs_sorted.bam
c_1_1   c_161045_1  3489    1178
c_1_2   c_161045_2  216 75
c_1_3   c_161045_3  1335    425
c_1_4   c_161045_4  201 106
```

File 2:

```
Geneid  KO_ID   KO_function
c_161045_3  NA  NA
c_161045_4  K07733  prophage regulatory protein
c_161045_6  NA  NA
c_161045_7  NA  NA
c_161045_8  NA  NA
```

Field $2 in File 1 matches Field $1 in File 2. **My goal is to create the following file with them merged together:**

Result File:

```
 Geneid KO_ID   KO_function Length  Coverage
    c_161045_3  NA  NA  3489    1178
    c_161045_4  K07733  prophage regulatory protein 216 75
    c_161045_6  NA  NA  1335    425
    c_161045_7  NA  NA  201 106
```

**The Result file should contain fields $1, $2, and $3 from File 2, and fields $3 and $4 from File 1.**

Here is what I have tried so far, but it is not working. This code only adds $4 from File 1 into the Result file, not $3 and $4 from File 1...

```
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} NR==FNR {a[$1]=$3; a[$2]=$4;next} FNR==1 {print "Gene_ID", "KO_ID" ,"KO_Function", "Coverage";} FNR>1($1 in a) {print $1, $2, $3, a[$1], a[$2]}' File1 File2 > ResultFile
```

Here is the result from what I have tried thus far ($3 from File 2 aka the "Length" column is missing):

```
Gene_ID KO_ID   KO_Function Length  Coverage
c_161045_3  NA  NA  425
c_161045_4  K07733  prophage regulatory protein 106     
c_161045_6  NA  NA  207
c_161045_7  NA  NA  687
```

Can someone help me please figure out what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

**EDIT**: I have added a screenshot showing the head of these two files and the tails of these two files. The answer below does merge based on file matches - but the merging stops when the beginning of the pattern changes.

[image: showing tails and heads of two files I am trying to merge; you can see where they have the same patterns in either $1 or $2.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you get the expected outcome if you make these minor tweaks?

Example data:

```
head file*
==> file_1.txt <==
Geneid  Chr Length  DP_D_9_8_21_B_contigs_sorted.bam
c_1_1   c_161045_1  3489    1178
c_1_2   c_161045_2  216 75
c_1_3   c_161045_3  1335    425
c_1_4   c_161045_4  201 106

==> file_2.txt <==
Geneid  KO_ID   KO_function
c_161045_3  NA  NA
c_161045_4  K07733  prophage regulatory protein
c_161045_6  NA  NA
c_161045_7  NA  NA
c_161045_8  NA  NA
```

Potential solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR {a[$2] = $3 FS $4} NR==1 {print "Gene_ID", "KO_ID" ,"KO_Function", "Length", "Coverage"} NR > FNR{if($1 in a) {print $1, $2, $3, a[$1]}}' file_1.txt file_2.txt
Gene_ID KO_ID   KO_Function Length  Coverage
c_161045_3  NA  NA  1335    425
c_161045_4  K07733  prophage regulatory protein 201 106
```

(Nicer formatting)

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = "\t"
}

NR == FNR {
    a[$2] = $3 FS $4
}

NR == 1 {
    print "Gene_ID", "KO_ID", "KO_Function", "Length", "Coverage"
}

NR > FNR {
    if ($1 in a) {
        print $1, $2, $3, a[$1]
    }
}' file_1.txt file_2.txt
```

Comment: I thougt this worked, but for some reason I am losing a ton of information in the output file. The File 1s and File 2s I am using are not the same length, and they are not sorted - but they are in the same order by their shared value...not sure what is going on. The matches between File 1 and File two go up to "c_4937153_64" for the gene ID, but the result file stops at "c_16919_136"...

Comment: That's no good; what do your actual files look like? Are they the same as the examples you provided in your question? How are the fields separated? Also, how large are the files/fields you want to capture?

Comment: The files do look the same as what I shared, but they are rather big files. The fields are \t separated. These files range from 1-100+ KB.

Comment: It seems that the awk matches work for the matches that start with c_16919_ (start of File 2 in $2) - but when the pattern changes to the next set of labels (c_31976_1, c_31976_2, etc) the merging stops.

Comment: The command is looking for exact matches; do you have the exact matching ID in both file1 and file2?

Comment: I just realized they don't have exact matches...a new problem arises. I am going to try and fix this other awk related issue and try your suggestion again. Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: I am finally revisiting this code and was wondering if you could explain why we assign the fields of interest ($3 FS $4) to a[$2], but print a[$1] into our output? I am trying to better understand the awk array structure for my notes, thank you so much! @jared_mamrot